# Excel: Convert to Txt Comma Separator With a Tab Deliminator File

Tags: microsoft-excel, text-editors, csv

I had a text file that used a comma separation value.

I imported the file into Excel, used Text to Columns, and changed to a tab deliminator, so I can work on the file.

I've completed the work on the file and now want to convert back to a text file with a comma separator.

This is what I have:
[image: tabseparator]

This is what I want:
[image: Commaseparator]

Any suggestions?

Comment: I loaded the file into my linux machine and did the following command

[5:23 PM] Marcelo Guimarães: 

cat file.txt | sed "s/\t/,/g" >> file.out.csv

Comment: If you have an answer (that's acceptable to you), post it as an answer. If the `sed` solution *isn't* acceptable to you, [edit] it into the question with an explanation of why it isn't acceptable.

Comment: Done.  
Thanks Scott. I'm a new super user =0

Answer (score 1):

I loaded the file into my linux machine and did the following command

```
cat file.txt | sed "s/\t/,/g" >> file.out.csv
```

Comment: (1) Please see [Useless use of cat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29#Useless_use_of_cat).  (2) Based on what you’ve said in the question, you probably don’t need `>>` — see [What are the shell's control and redirection operators?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/159513/23408).  `>` should be good enough.   So your command can be reduced to `sed "s/\t/,/g" file.txt > file.out.csv`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any reason you need to convert to Tab separated to work on the file... Are you sure you're importing the CSV, not just opening it with Excel (which are not the same thing)?

Just "really" import it straight from CSV and keep it as such.

To do that open fresh workbook or worksheet, click on first cell and do the following:

1. Click Tab "Data"
2. Choose option "Get External Data from Text" from the list
3. In first dialog window choose the CSV file to import
4. Next dialog window - choose "Delimited"
5. And then, at next step, tick option "comma" from Delimiters
6. Finish.

You then get imported CSV in Excel you can work on and then, at the end, just save with `CTRL+S`.

EDIT: Exporting file to CSV in Excel is accomplished by selectin option "Save as..." and then from the list choose "Other formats" and in the window that pops up select CSV from "Save as type" drop-down.
Another way is to open the saved TSV file in any text editor and simply replace all tab occurences with comma or any other symbol. Just did it with notepad: opened TSV, copied tab, pasted into "Replace all" window and replace with had comma. Worked like a charm.

Comment: The file was as tab separated.

Comment: @JesseMacDougall Then you should remove the bit that contradicts above comment. From my side - added bit on exporting data to CSV in Excel.

Comment: The file was originally comma separated, I converted it to tab, then back to comma, issue solved all good thanks